# I need part of the page to be changed dynamically with ajax

Tags: ajax, dynamic

I just finished wireframing and need to dynamically change main part of the page which is a div class="container" with sliced parts of the page which represent other content that will be injected into index.html

please see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYiTn.jpg

The RED part needs to be swapped dynamically with other .html when above links clicked. And the static parts which are blue, stays.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 5%;

            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/slider-pro.css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/examples.css" media="screen"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>




    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><big>Chris Kalmar</big> <small>portfolio</small></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class"container-fluid">
     <div class"row">
     <div class"col-xs-6">

      <ul>
          <li class="branding"><a href="#brand">Branding</a></li>
          <li class="3d"><a href="#3d">3D</a></li>
          <li class="Apps"><a href="#app">Apps</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="container">

    <!-- ajax call--> 




    <!-- /ajax call--> 


    </div><!-- / container--> 



     <footer>
        <p>Chris Kalmar - All rights reserved 2015</p>
    </footer>


       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var router = {
        "#brand" : "http://www.chriskalmar.com/branding.html",
        "#3d" : "http://www.chriskalmar.com/3d.html",
    };
    $(window).on("hashchange", function(){
        var route = router[location.hash];
        if (route === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        else {            
            $(".container").load( "" + route + " #content" );
        }            
    });
});
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your html too. also, post the js error logs(by going to browser js console, in chrome press f12)

Comment: hi Nishad, just edited  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, what I do is create a route handler full of url hashes mapped to urls. That way, when I listen for a window hashchange event, I can route to that hash's corresponding url. The object would look like this:

```
var router = {
    "#ajax" : "http://fiddle.jshell.net"
};
```

Then I use this object to acquire html from the url asynchronously, using the router and a jquery get request (on hashchange):

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function(){
    var route = router[location.hash];
    if (typeof route === 'undefined') return;            
    $.get( route, function( data ) {
        $( ".sliderContent" ).html( data );
    });                
});
```

As you can see from the jquery get's callback, the ajax data retrieved is injected into the DOM in the sliderContent div. I hope this helps :)

See the working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrLLhq30/5/

Edit: the AJAX takes a little while to process, so give it a bit of time to load.

**UPDATE**

I've updated my fiddle to include multiple links (as well as replacing the jquery `get` with a jquery `load`, just to speed up the resource retrieval) and, as you can see, the content inside the divs load into the container without a page refresh.

If you implement the solution they way I did, using different hashes for each resource URL, then it should work great. I hope this is what you meant :)

Updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrLLhq30/7/

Comment: Yes but i need to navigate through few links the page loads but needs to be refreshed every time see here: http://www.chriskalmar.com

Comment: I see! Sorry for the misunderstanding. Whenever I need to force reload an element on a page loaded with AJAX, I usually append a time-based modifier to the URL. For instance, I'd add a `Date.getTime()` query at the end of the URL I'm loading. I haven't fully looked over your code as I'm at work, but if you're still struggling I'll solve it later this evening.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. It needs deeper understanding than mine. maybe is something with cache i don't know... i just need to make part of the page dynamic and footer, navbar and sidebar to stay static.

Comment: No problem Chris. Take a quick look at my update, see if that sheds any light on the situation. I think so long as you use different hashes, the need for a page refresh shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: GET http://www.branding.html/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when I upload to server i am getting this error in chrome dev tools GET http://www.branding.html/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Hate to say it but an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a minefield - usually has something to do with DNS resolution. I'd post a separate question on that one, with specifics, or google around for the solution to that one.

Comment: Tried everything so far.I just can't do it properly. I thought it was simple to make part of the page dynamic  but it isn't .

Comment: Just looked over your code. The problem is, in your router object, the URLs you're trying to retrieve are `http://www.branding.html` and `http://www.3d.html`, which are both a) invalid URLs and b) not URLs which point to your site's resources. Your resources would be at a URL like `http://www.chriskalmar.com/resources/branding.html`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I just updated the code as you suggest. I don't know why this don't work. i tried in your fiddle to swap the addresses with mine and neither don't work.

Comment: It appears that the domain name that points to your website's IP is `chriskalmar.com`, and not `www.chriskalmar.com`. Omit / delete the `www` from the URLs in the router object.

Comment: just updated on the server and with changed url's                $(document).ready(function(){
    var router = {
        "#brand" : "http://chriskalmar.com/branding.html",
        "#3d" : "http://chriskalmar.com/3d.html",
    };
    $(window).on("hashchange", function(){
        var route = router[location.hash];
        if (route === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        else {            
            $(".container").load( "" + route + " #content" );
        }            
    });
});

Comment: Are you sure your html is located in the root folder? If you're having trouble at some point in the AJAX process, you should use `console.log()`s to see where your code halts.

Comment: in console log nothing, no errors, no warnings, nothing  yep it's in public_html root folder

Comment: can you please connect my adresses with your fiddle. to see for yourself if it's work this way

Answer (score 0):

this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` happens propably due to missing a closing parenthesis. So in your jquery click function, outer closing parenthesis will be missing. I have examined your code and yes you are missing closing paranthesis.

Also this error related answer is alreday here:[JavaScript error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983088/javascript-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)

```
$(function () { $(".branding").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'branding.html',
                        data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $(".container").replaceWith(data);  //try with double qoutes
                        }
                    });
                });
                });//this is the missing paranthesis


$(function () { $(".3d").click(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '3d.html',
                            data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $(".container").replaceWith(data);  //try with double qoutes
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    });//this is the missing paranthesis
```