# Handling random number of links by using AJAX Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new at AJAX and JQuery and trying to use them in the part of my website. Basically the website that I have, has this kind of design and currently it is functional (Sorry for my poor paint work :) [image: website]

The items in the website are created by user. This means item number is not constant but can be fetched by db query. 
Each item has a unique URL and currently when you click an item, all page is refreshing. I want to change the system to let the user have a chance to navigate quickly between these items by only chaning middle content area as shown above. However I also want to have a unique URL to each item. I mean if the item has a name like "stack overflow", I want the item to have a URL kind of dev.com/#stack-overflow or similar. 
I don't mind about the "#" that may come from AJAX.

In similar topics I have seen people hold constant names for items. For instance
 `<a href="#ajax">` but my items are not constant.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Whats my idea is; while fetching all item's links, I'm holding links in $link variable and using it in `<a href="#<?php echo $link; ?>">`. 
Inside $link it is not actual URL. it is for instance a name like "stack-overflow" as I ve given example above. Until this part there is no problem.

**PROBLEM**

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133755/i-need-part-of-the-page-to-be-changed-dynamically-with-ajax?lq=1) a friend suggested this kind of code as an idea and I ve changed it for my purpose.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var router = {
        "<?php echo $link ?> ": "http://localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php"
      };
      $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        var route = router[location.hash];
        if (route === undefined) {
          return;
        } else {
          $(".content-right").load("" + route + " #ortadaki_baslik");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to post the value of $link to the link_process.php and at link_process.php I will get the value of $link and arrange neccessary page content to show. 
The questions are; 
 - How should I change this code to do that? 
 - I couldnt see someone doing similar to take as an example solve this
   issue. Is this the right way to solve this situation?
 - Do you guys have a better solution or suggestion for my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I built a website which I _think_ does what you describe. It is called [Community Casts](http://communitycast.co/). The source code is [here](https://github.com/alexbooker/communitycasts.co) if you want to try and learn from it. You may have more success using a front-end technology with a _router_ like [Vue](http://vuejs.org/) or Angular.

Answer (score 0):

**WHEN** your server side AJAX call handler [PHP script - handling AJAX requests at server side] is constant and you are passing item_id/link as GET parameter...

**For example:**
localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php?item_id=stack-overflow **OR**
localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php?item_id=stack-exchange

**Then** you can use following code.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ajax_handler = "localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php?item_id=";
      $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        var route = location.hash;
        if (route === undefined) {
          return;
        } else {
          route = route.slice(1); //Removing hash character
          $(".content-right").load( ajax_handler + route );
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

---

**WHEN** you are passing item_id/link as URL part and not parameter...

**For example:**
localhost/ajax_tut/stack-overflow.php **OR**
localhost/ajax_tut/stack-exchange.php

**Then** you can use following code.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ajax_handler = "localhost/ajax_tut/";
      $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        var route = location.hash;
        if (route === undefined) {
          return;
        } else {
          route = route.slice(1); //Removing hash character
          $(".content-right").load( ajax_handler + route + ".php");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

---

**WHEN** Your server side AJAX handler script url is not constant and varies for different items...

**For example:** localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php?item_id=stack-overflow **OR** localhost/ajax_tut/fetch_item.php?item_id=stack-exchange **OR** localhost/ajax_tut/stack-exchange.php

**Then** I suggest to change PHP script which is generating item's links placed on left hand side.

```
<?php
  foreach($links as $link){
      // Make sure that you are populating route parameter correctly
      echo '<a href="'.$link['item_id'].'" route="'.$link['full_ajax_handler_route_url_path'].'" >'.$link['title'].'</a>'; 
  }
?>
```

Here is Javascript

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ajax_handler = "localhost/ajax_tut/"; //Base url or path
      $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        var route = location.hash;
        if (route === undefined) {
          return;
        } else {
          route = route.slice(1); //Removing hash character
          route = $('a [href="'+.slice(1)+'"]').attr('route'); //Fetching ajax URL
          $(".content-right").load( ajax_handler + route ); //Here you need to design your url based on need
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I guess the scenerio I'm in is the last one. Well, I tried to impelement it. I already have that loop  php in the code. `foreach ($list as $item) {
<a href="<?php echo $item->$id; ?>" route="localhost/ajax_tut/link_process.php" ><?php echo $item->title; ?>}`
However since in href I'm using `$item->id`, the items have this kind of link localhost/ajax_tut/stack-overflow  and doesnt work. I didnt understand how exactly I need to format the Route tag. Is it wrong now?

Comment: Your case is second one Below is your code for HTML like
 `<?php
   foreach($list as $item){
    echo '<a href="#'.$item->id.'" >'.$item->title.'</a>'; 
   }
 ?>`

Comment: And Javascript be like `<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ajax_handler = "localhost/ajax_tut/";
      $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        var route = location.hash;
        if (route === undefined) {
          return;
        } else {
          route = route.slice(1); //Removing hash character
          $(".content-right").load( ajax_handler + route);
        }
      });
    });
</script>`

Comment: But you didnt write the name of ajax handler there. Well even I tried it didnt work. It doesnt change the content since it doesnt call link_process.php successfully. and I also need to pass $item-> id to link process.

Comment: Can you prepare or share a test url or page so that I can have a look at before suggesting specific solution ?